# Whatsapp api to let visitors contact us on whatsapp

Tags: whatsapp, whatsapi

In my holiday site I want to add whatsapp communication with visitor. I need whatsapp api to let visitors contact us on whatsapp. I have check multiple solution for this but don't find any solution yet for this.

I need functionality like below

[image: whatsapp]

Comment: you just need visitor to  contact you on whasapp right..?

Comment: yes I need visitor contact me on whatsapp

Answer (score 1):

WhatsApp provides a custom URL **(whatsapp://send?text=)** to send message with WhatsApp.
    WhatsApp's Click to Chat feature allows you to begin a chat with someone without having their phone number saved in your phone's address book. As long as you know this person’s phone number, you can create a link that will allow you to start a chat with them. By clicking the link, a chat with the person automatically opens. Click to Chat works on both your phone and WhatsApp Web.

```
https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=number here
```

usage :

```
 <a href=" https://api.whatsapp.com/send?
 phone=whatsappphonenumber&text=urlencodedtext">send</a>
```

where whatsappphonenumber is a full phone number in international format and urlencodedtext is the URL-encoded pre-filled message.

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have use this [https://api.whatsapp.com/send?31651566745] link but it display me "This link is incorrect. Close this window and try a different link."

Comment: try this     ` https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=whatsappphonenumber&text=urlencodedtext`     where whatsappphonenumber is a full phone number in international format and urlencodedtext is the URL-encoded pre-filled message.

Comment: @VimalPatel .i have updated the answer just check this

Comment: I have try [api.whatsapp.com/send/?phone=919558449166&text=hi] but it display me "The address wasn't understood: